# How to vertically center the Edit Text in Vcl.ExtCtrls.TButtonedEdit?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin

`Vcl.ExtCtrls.TButtonedEdit` is a standard VCL control. Unfortunately, the Edit Text is vertically attached to the TOP which looks very ugly instead of being vertically centered:

[image]

[image]

This is how it should look like instead:

[image]

Here is the object code:

```
object tlbFilter: TToolBar
  AlignWithMargins = True
  Left = 1
  Top = 30
  Width = 322
  Height = 24
  Margins.Left = 0
  Margins.Top = 5
  Margins.Right = 0
  Margins.Bottom = 2
  BorderWidth = 1
  Color = clBtnFace
  DoubleBuffered = True
  EdgeInner = esNone
  EdgeOuter = esRaised
  Images = ImageList16
  ParentColor = False
  ParentDoubleBuffered = False
  TabOrder = 2
  Transparent = False
  DesignSize = (
    318
    20)
  object edtFilter: TButtonedEdit
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 315
    Height = 22
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight]
    BorderStyle = bsNone
    Images = ImageList16
    LeftButton.Enabled = False
    LeftButton.ImageIndex = 7
    LeftButton.Visible = True
    RightButton.DisabledImageIndex = 46
    RightButton.HotImageIndex = 2
    RightButton.ImageIndex = 45
    RightButton.PressedImageIndex = 31
    RightButton.Visible = True
    TabOrder = 0
  end
end
```

So how can I vertically center the Edit Text in `Vcl.ExtCtrls.TButtonedEdit`?

Comment: By setting BorderStyle to bsSingle.

Comment: You can achieve the same artifact with any Edit BTW, by setting border style to none.

Comment: I've done so, and now it still looks ugly as the left glyph is vertically attached to the bottom (which was not before): http://i.imgur.com/7abbaWE.png

Comment: And I cannot set the Edit height to less than 22.

Comment: I guess you should also set AutoSize, left image does not bottom with my test here.

Comment: I notice the images horrendously flicker when I pass over mouse. Perhaps the control is not exactly prime time ready.

Comment: `AutoSize` was already set the whole time. But now I got a somewhat satisfactory result by using 18x17 glyphs, setting the font size from 8 to 9 and setting the font quality to `fqClearType`.

Comment: Here the glyphs do not flicker when I pass the mouse over them.

Comment: I was writing an answer that employed WM_NCCALCSIZE when I thought of testing with some big fonts. Stock or modified, text ok but images go bonkers. You'll have to have all kinds of image sizes. I'd give up on this control.

Comment: Now I've too noticed that the glyphs FLICKER TERRIBLY when I enter text QUICKLY and while I SELECT text in the Edit. Maybe I'll really give up with this control. Does anybody know a similar control with better quality?